# Single Resource File for all Windows Qt

Tags: qt, window, resource-files

I'm new to Qt. I'm developing an application which has several windows and currently I have to create a separate resource file for each window. I'm just wondering if it's possible to have a single resource file for all my windows.

Is it possible? if yes then how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `.qrc` files?

Comment: Probably you should start here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: yes. I'm talking about .qrc files.

Comment: Actually I'm working on Qt designer. Currently, when I create a new window and try to set "WindowIcon" in properties panel, no resource is listed there in "Choose Resource". However, if I add a new resource file into the project, it gets listed in "Choose Resource" .